# How to set baseurl in aspx file site.master page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, master-pages

I want to set baseurl in my sitemaster aspx file .

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="<%=Request.Url.Scheme + \"://\" + Request.Url.Authority +  Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + \"/\"; %>" class="nav-link">

        <i class="nav-icon fas fa-th"></i>
        <p>Back</p>
    </a>
</li>
```

I am getting an error

> Compilation Error
>
> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.
>
> Compiler Error Message: CS1056: Unexpected character '\'
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 67:           `</li>`
>   Line 68:           `<li class="nav-item">`
>   Line 69:             `<a href="<%=Request.Url.Scheme + \"://\" + Request.Url.Authority +  Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + \"/\"; %>" class="nav-link">`
>   Line 70:
>   Line 71:

I search in google and try so many solutions, but none work for me.
I want to set server base url to a link `site.master` file.

Comment: `site.master` is a part of ASP.NET **Webforms** - but ASP.NET **Core** (that you mention in your tags) does **not** support webforms .....

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove those slashes. You don't need to escape the `"`. Only when using it inside a string `"this is an \"example\" string.";`

```
<%= Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority +  Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/" %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle this in Site.Master is to use "~/" for the root path and then add `runat="server"` even if it is not an ASP.NET control.

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="~/" runat="server">Navbar Brand</a>
...
<ul class="nav navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <li class="nav-item"><a href="~/" runat="server" class="nav-link text-white">Home</a></li>
```